# Alternatives to Unit Testing?

Tags: software-verification, applications

During a technical interview I was asked about ways to make sure code/software design is functional before deploying to any servers and the only thing I could think of was unit testing. My interviewer pressed me for other ways but I couldn't come up with any alternatives.

Comment: Try at [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: This is not really a computer *science* question, but there are several ways in which you can *increase your confidence* (there is no such thing as absolute certainty in life) that your code has no show-stopping bugs. Unit testing is one of them, but there other kinds of testing: property-based testing, integration testing, fuzzing, etc. Code reviews are another way in which you can increase your confidence in your code: several people are more likely to find mistakes than just one. And there are formal methods, although they are not too popular in a business setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are several ways to ensure product/code quality and functionality before deployment:**

1. Basic functionality testing
2. Code Review
3. Static code analysis
4. Unit Testing
5. Single user performance testing